# Line circle with shadow swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, shadow, uibezierpath

I created line circle with shadow, but when I tried to change `shadowRadius`, the shadow was not showing

```
let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
let shapeLayer              = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path             = path.cgPath
shapeLayer.fillColor        = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor      = UIColor.white.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth        = 1
shapeLayer.shadowOpacity    = 0.9
shapeLayer.shadowColor      = UIColor.white.cgColor
shapeLayer.shadowOffset     = .zero
shapeLayer.shadowRadius     = 10.0
//shapeLayer.shadowPath       = path.cgPath

layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

[line circle with default corner radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DZNC.png)

[line circle with corner radius 10.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1nkx.png)

Can someone help me?

Comment: The shadow is there in the picture, it's just faint.

Comment: Yes, but I want bigger shadow with radius more than 20.0. And when I set this radius, I did not see shadow

Comment: Can you add output desired image ?

Comment: added output image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to create the effect off a "stronger" shadow, you can do so by using a shadow path that has been stroked to be larger than the path that's "casting the shadow". This can be achieved using [`copy(strokingWithWidth:lineCap:lineJoin:miterLimit:transform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpath/2427133-copy):

```
shapeLayer.shadowPath = path.cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: width, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 0)
```

This is what such a shadow (in red) looks like, both with and without any blur (shadow radius):

[image: stroked shadow path with and without blur]

You can configure the `shadowBlur` and the `width` of the stroked shadow path to achieve the effect that you're after. Below are some examples:

[image: A few variations of shadow radius and shadow path stroke width]